# Maven Failed to Find dependency : prompt error of 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, kotlin, maven-2

I'm a newbie on Kotlin, Maven, and SpringBoot.

I encounter a problem when trying to build up the sample kotlin project. I actually did add external jar that needed. I just cut a few lines of error out because the other project has the same error.

```
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.jxinternet.platform:ms-common:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.jxinternet.platform:kotlin-starters:pom:1.0.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 13
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' of POM com.jxinternet.platform:ms-account:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Development File\eclipse-workspace\kotlin-starters\ms-account\pom.xml) points at com.jxinternet.platform:kotlin-starters instead of com.jxinternet.platform:dao-starters, please verify your project structure @ line 3, column 13
@ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 9 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.jxinternet.platform:ms-data:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Development File\eclipse-workspace\kotlin-starters\ms-data\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.jxinternet.platform:ms-data:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.jxinternet.platform:kotlin-starters:pom:1.0.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
```

below is my build configuration. * I follow some StackOverflow answer*
[image: my build configuration]

This is my main POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-starters</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ms-parent</name>

    <modules>
        <module>otp</module>
        <module>ms-data</module>
        <module>ms-common</module>
        <module>ms-account</module>
        <module>ms-order</module>
        <module>ms-su-web</module>
        <module>ms-plugin-web</module>
        <module>ms-merchant-web</module>
        <module>ms-scheduled-task</module>
        <module>ms-payment-web</module>
        <!--<module>ms-test</module>-->
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.boot.redis.version>1.4.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.redis.version>
        <logback.verion>4.11</logback.verion>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>otp</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- inner -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>ms-common</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>ms-data</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>ms-account</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>ms-order</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- spring -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.redis.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
                <version>${logback.verion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>maven-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://192.168.1.25:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>maven-releases</name>
            <url>http://192.168.1.25:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

One of my child pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>kotlin-starters</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ms-account</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- inner -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>ms-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>ms-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>otp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jxinternet.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>money-system-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Guys, I super newbie, I don't know what caused the error and don't know how to fix this. I'm looking for StackOverflow answer, some say look for my m2 folder. But i would'n know what to look for...I so lose. Thanks, guys.

Comment: You can find your .m2 dir in your user folder by default. Check to see the settings in {maven_installed_dir}\conf\setting.xml to see if its not found in user dir.

Comment: in my .m2 dir only have repository and doesn't have settings.xml. Am i missing something during build?

Answer (score 1):

Your parent version is `1.0-SNAPSHOT` yet in the child `pom.xml` for `ms-data` you're specifying parent version as `1.0.1`. It should be `1.0-SNAPSHOT`. Check all others as well so the parent version matches.